# How to impliment explicit wait in capybara to wait for element ,ruby

Tags: capybara

I want to implement explicit wait in capybara, site prism framework.
I have given `capybera.defaulteaitTime=18`. But then I have also to give say sleep 3 like some actions.
I am working in hybris PIM automation. Basically I want to avoid all sleep statements in code.

Comment: Show one example of the code you want to change

Answer (score 0):

SitePrism overrides Capybaras default waiting/retrying behavior, instead expecting you to use the provided [wait methods](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#waiting-for-an-element-to-exist-on-a-page).  You can however configure SitePrism to revert to the normal Capybara behavior of automatically waiting/retrying for elements by setting

```
SitePrism.configure do |config|
  config.use_implicit_waits = true
end
```

as documented [here](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#using-capybara-implicit-waits)